# Microsoft membership management, multiple instances in the same database

Tags: c#, membership

I have a database with the membership manager installed, is there a way to install another copy of the membership manager in the same database?  Change the prefix to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the application identifier in the .config file to differentiate between your applications. It's in the Membership Provider section. `applicationName="MyApplication"`

Answer (score 1):

If this is for another application, you can change your application name in the web.config file to something else in your new app.  The same tables/database are used but user information is separated.